# Extension for LibreOffice to show word definition

Tags: linux, dictionary, libreoffice

Anyone know an extension that adds a "lookup word" to the context menu for selected word? Doesn't need to be locally defined. It can show a definition from the internet, but I'd prefer it if it showed in in a native dialog box or something similar rather than a search engine. Needs to be Linux compatible.

Answer (score 1):

[Artha](https://sourceforge.net/projects/artha/) is a free dictionary add-on for Linux that integrates with most applications. It is available from Sourceforge, or in the Ubuntu software repo.

Comment: While that's not _exactly_ what I was looking for, it works perfectly for what I wanted. Thank you sir.